# rhs of magrittr pipe returns FALSE when lhs is placed in !()

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I encountered an issue using the `magrittr %>%` where an unexpected output is produced when the `lhs` is wrapped in `!()`. For example, I expected the output of these two lines to be identical.

```
sum( !( c(1,2,3,4) == 1 ) )
```

```
!( c(1,2,3,4) == 1 ) %>% sum()
```

However, the first line returns "3", as expected, whereas the second line returns "FALSE". Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is of precedence, wrap `(..)` around the first expression and it behaves as expected.

```
(!(c(1,2,3,4) == 1)) %>% sum
#[1] 3
```

You can find the precedence table at `?Syntax` where you can see that `%any%` is of higher precedence than `!`.

Answer (score 0):

With `%>%`, we can use the negate (`!`) also in chaining

```
library(magrittr)
( c(1,2,3,4) == 1 ) %>%
        `!` %>%
         sum
#[1] 3
```

---

Or use the `aliases` from `magrittr`

```
c(1, 2, 3, 4) %>%
   equals(1) %>% 
   not %>%
   sum
#[1] 3
```